# Class error in new object

Tags: ruby

My code isnt working! it says the following in the terminal

> undefined local variable or method pikachu for main:Object
>   (NameError)

code :

```
class Pokemon  
  def initialize(type, name, attack, hp) 
    # Instance variables  
    @type = type  
    @name = name  
    @attack = attack    
    @hp = hp     
  end  

  def display  
    puts "This is #{@name} it is a #{@type} type and has #{@attack} attack and #{@hp} hp"  
  end
end

p = pikachu.new("eletric", "pikachu", "100", "200")
p.initialize  
p.display`
```

Answer (score 2):

> undefined local variable or method pikachu for main:Object (NameError)

Your **class name** is `Pokemon` but you are using `pikachu` which resulted in that error. You should use `Pokemon`

```
p = Pokemon.new("eletric", "pikachu", "100", "200")
```

Also remove `p.initialize` which is unnecessary as `initialize` will eventually be called by `new`

Comment: well, i had to take out the p.initialize but after that is worked! thanks btw